# Emacs / AUCTeX search/replace in multifile documents

Tags: emacs, auctex

Is there a way to let emacs automatically search and replace strings/regex in all files that are part of a multifile document? With `C-s` or `M-%` only the current buffer is included in the search, even if `TeX-master` variable is set.

I'm using GNU Emacs 24.3.1

Comment: classic way is to use tags-query-replace (with etags)

Comment: What version of Emacs are you using?

Comment: Enable reftex, it contains features to search and replace (I think it is based on David's answer). Always pair auctex with reftex. Makes your life easier

Comment: @daleif That's it: `reftex-query-replace-document` and `reftex-search-document`. Please add it as solution so I can accept it.

Comment: @S1lentSt0rm.  Done

Comment: Related: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/737/2264

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When ever you use `emacs` and `auctex` always remember to enable reftex as well or you will miss out on all sorts of useful goodies. In this case `reftex-query-replace-document` and `reftex-search-document`. Another one I like is the label rename feature, really nice.

Comment: In addition, `reftex-isearch-minor-mode` lets you use normal `C-s` key stroke to search the whole multifile document. thanks!

Comment: @S1lentSt0rm Wow, I never knew I missed this!